# AQL match strings with multiple slashes

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have records in Artifactory like this:

```
{
    "path": "amc-sw/pcm33/pcm21/system-pcm33-20221017104012.raucb",
    "type": "file",
```

Now I want to match all records having pcm21 in the path.

I run this query and it gives me a lot of records

```
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "amc-sw",
          "$and": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "path": {
                    "$match": "*pcm21/*"
                  }
} ] } ] } } } ] }
```

```
jf rt search --spec query.json --url=$ARTIFACTORY_URL --user=$ARTIFACTORY_USER --access-token=$ARTIFACTORY_PASS
```

Changing the match to this also gives a lot of records

```
                    "$match": "*/pcm21*"
```

But this gives me exactly zero records

```
                    "$match": "*/pcm21/*"
```

Why can't I use two slashes in the matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind `"$match": "*/pcm21/*"` returning 0 results derives from the path structure `"path": "amc-sw/pcm33/pcm21/system-pcm33-20221017104012.raucb",`

The file `system-pcm33-20221017104012.raucb` comes right after the deepest folder which is pcm21.

The match structure with ending forward slash requires an additional directory after the pcm21.

assuming the path would have been `amc-sw/pcm33/pcm21/inner-path/system-pcm33-20221017104012.raucb`

the query would return:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "repo": "amc-sw",
        "path": "pcm33/pcm21/inner-path",
        "name": "system-pcm33-20221017104012.raucb",
        "type": "file",
        "size": 385,
        "created": "2023-03-30T06:19:30.268Z",
        "created_by": "admin",
        "modified": "2023-03-30T06:19:06.638Z",
        "modified_by": "admin",
        "updated": "2023-03-30T06:19:30.268Z"
    }
],
"range": {
    "start_pos": 0,
    "end_pos": 1,
    "total": 1
}
```

}